# How can I make a bootstrap media list with a scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
   
  </style> 
 </head>
 <body class="p-1">
  <div class="p-0 container-fluid">
   <div class="p-0 row h-25 no-gutters">
    <div class="p-0 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
     <video id="selfView" class="h-100 w-100 position-absolute" controls muted>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="p-0 row no-gutters">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center p-0 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
     <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn btn-sm btn-lg btn-success">
      TV:<span class="badge badge-success">On</span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="shareVideo" checked>
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-success">
      Light:<span class="badge badge-success">On</span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="shareAudio" checked>
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-danger">
      Air Cond:<span class="badge badge-danger">Off</span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="shareScreen">
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1">
      <button class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-success">Create a meeting</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="p-0 row no-gutters">
    <div class="p-0 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
     <ul class="nav nav-pills p-1 d-flex justify-content-around" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link active" 
        id="pills-info-tab" data-toggle="pill" 
        href="#pills-info" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-info" aria-selected="true">
        i
       </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" 
        id="pills-member-tab" data-toggle="pill" 
        href="#pills-member" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-member" aria-selected="false">
        f
       </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" 
        id="pills-message-tab" data-toggle="pill" 
        href="#pills-message" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-message" aria-selected="false">
        c
       </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="tab-content border border-success position-relative" id="pills-tabContent"> 
      
       <div class="tab-pane fade p-0 show active " id="pills-info" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-member-tab">
        <ul class="list-unstyled overflow-auto h-100">
          <li class="media">
         a
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         b
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         c
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         a
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         b
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         c
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         a
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         b
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         c
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         a
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         b
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         c
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         a
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         b
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         c
          </li>
                  <li class="media">
         a
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         b
          </li>
          <li class="media">
         c
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade p-0" id="pills-member" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-member-tab"> 
        2
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade p-0" id="pills-message" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-member-tab"> 
        3
       </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the bootstrap media list(i.e line 81) with a scroll bar?

I have using a "position-relative" and "position-absolute" class to make the browser show a scroll bar.

Unfortunately, it does not work.

It is because when I browse the web page with a mobile phone the media list is too long.

Comment: with css, set div height and use overflow:scroll

Comment: I want to set the height of div equal to  the rest of height browser, however, I don't know how do so.

Comment: my answer is below addresses that. ie use calc function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS, place this into the empty `<style></style>` tag, and remove the `overflow-auto h-100` classes from the `ul`.

```
#pills-info {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

Comment: Would you tell why minus 100px ?

Comment: its roughly the height of the nav section, it can be tweaked

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar can be added by using a CSS class with these 2 attributes:

1. ***overflow-y: scroll***
2. ***max-height: height;***

---

**An example CSS class for scroll bar:**

```
        .scroll-bar {
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            max-height: 100px;
        }
```

**Here is the working example with CSS class added to the list:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <style>
            .scroll-bar {
                overflow-x: scroll;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                max-height: 100px;
            }
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body class="p-1">
        <div class="p-0 container-fluid">
            <div class="p-0 row h-25 no-gutters">
                <div class="p-0 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <video id="selfView" class="h-100 w-100 position-absolute" controls muted>
                        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 row no-gutters">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center p-0 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1" data-toggle="buttons">
                      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-lg btn-success">
                        TV:<span class="badge badge-success">On</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="shareVideo" checked>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1" data-toggle="buttons">
                      <label class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-success">
                        Light:<span class="badge badge-success">On</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="shareAudio" checked>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1" data-toggle="buttons">
                      <label class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-danger">
                        Air Cond:<span class="badge badge-danger">Off</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="shareScreen">
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle p-1">
                        <button class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-success">Create a meeting</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 row no-gutters">
                <div class="p-0 col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills p-1 d-flex justify-content-around" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" 
                                id="pills-info-tab" data-toggle="pill" 
                                href="#pills-info" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-info" aria-selected="true">
                                i
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" 
                                id="pills-member-tab" data-toggle="pill" 
                                href="#pills-member" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-member" aria-selected="false">
                                f
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" 
                                id="pills-message-tab" data-toggle="pill" 
                                href="#pills-message" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-message" aria-selected="false">
                                c
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content border border-success position-relative" id="pills-tabContent"> 

                            <div class="tab-pane fade p-0 show active" id="pills-info" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-member-tab">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled overflow-auto h-100 scroll-bar">
                                  <li class="media">
                                    a
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    b
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    c
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    a
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    b
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    c
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    a
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    b
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    c
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    a
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    b
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    c
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    a
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    b
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    c
                                  </li>
                  <li class="media">
                                    a
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    b
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="media">
                                    c
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade p-0" id="pills-member" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-member-tab">    
                                2
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade p-0" id="pills-message" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-member-tab">   
                                3
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]